# No resource found error in layout xml file android

Tags: android, xml, layout, resources

I get this error in xml file very often.
here is the code in xml file

```
 <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/tRowMain"   // in this line i get error resource not found that matches given name
        android:textColor="@color/selectLevel"
        android:id="@+id/tvOnOption"
        android:text="Select Mode"
        />      
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tRowMain"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
```

//then i checked in R.java file and the id for this name is there

```
public static final class id {
        public static final int ibtn_retry=0x7f060006;
        public static final int rLayoutMain=0x7f060000;
        public static final int tRowMain=0x7f060002;

    }
```

please help me figure out whats wrong with this...

thanks

Comment: Did you clean the project? restart eclipse and see.

Comment: Yes i did clean and fix project properties also but there was problem in code actually the below answer worked.. problem was: i was using an id before it was created. thanks for ur suggestion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the `@+id/tRowMain` syntax in the first place the ID is used, not necessarily the first place where you define it as the ID of the element.

Change:

`android:layout_above="@id/tRowMain"` to `android:layout_above="@+id/tRowMain"`

and

`android:id="@+id/tRowMain"` to `android:id="@id/tRowMain`

In other words, when deciding whether or not to use `@+id` or `@id`, it doesn't matter which attribute you're assigning the id to. Always use `@+id` the first time you mention your ID in the XML.

Comment: hey sorry i have not accepted the answer that time, thats why it didn't show up to you. i am new to this forum so i didn't know how to accept the answer i thought for that i have to just click on yes in front of "was this answer helpful" and i did that later i came to know that i have to check the white check mark on the top left corner of the answer block..

Comment: Thanks , i didn't know that time how to accept thats the only reason i didn't do now i got to know , i will keep this in mind ...

Answer (score 1):

```
android:layout_above="@+id/tRowMain"
```

If it does'nt work delete your R.java file. It will be re-generated